# Getting multiple values when using count function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a QUERY which is giving result as follwing

```
Name Count
A      10
B      5
C      2
```

and now i want get the number of rows of my query. So, i am using

```
SELECT COUNT(0) from QUERY;
```

and getting

```
COUNT
null
null
null
```

Comment: What exactly is `query` supposed to be? A table? A real query? If the latter, than show us that query.

Answer (score 1):

> and now i want get the number of rows of my query

Simply do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( here goes your query );`

> SELECT COUNT(0) from QUERY;

It should still give you the same as above.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(0) FROM
  2    ( SELECT * FROM emp
  3    );

  COUNT(0)
----------
        14

SQL>
```

Comment: i am trying same. Result is  3 rows containg null (in my case ). My inner query includes group by expression.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your inner query looks like? Please edit your question and post the details. Show using copy paste what exactly you are doing.